Vue3 composition api transform props multidimensional Array into list
I'm using vue3 with composition api and I receive a props from db as a multidimensional array on page loading like this:
[
   {name: 'Jack', seat: '12', id: 1, ...},
   {name: 'Jack', seat: '13', id: 2, ...},
   {name: 'Luis', seat: '21', id: 3, ...},
   {name: 'Manuel', seat: '4', id: 4, ...},
   {name: 'Jack', seat: '14', id: 5, ...},
   ...
]

I'm already using it to have a view in the page as a standard list one by one but I need to create another table, after the previous, with names and the list of your seats (in case more than one).
Example:
Jack: 12,13,14
Luis: 21
Manuel: 4,5,6
....

I tried to use a template but I have some problems to achive this result, I tried using table and div tags but the output is wrong with break line in the middle or skipping the row.
I don't know if there is a way to achive it without change the props structure (to have no problems on the previous table)
do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance
Roberto

Use computed and transform your data into needed format inside it:
Playground
<script setup>
import { onMounted, reactive, computed} from 'vue'
const data = reactive([]);

onMounted(async() => {
   const fetchedData = await [
   {name: 'Jack', seat: '12', id: 1},
   {name: 'Jack', seat: '13', id: 2},
   {name: 'Luis', seat: '21', id: 3},
   {name: 'Manuel', seat: '4', id: 4},
   {name: 'Jack', seat: '14', id: 5},
   ];

   data.push(...fetchedData);
});
const seats = computed(() => 
  data.reduce((r, {name, seat}) => ((r[name] ??= []).push(seat),r), {}));
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="(nums, name) in seats" :key="name">
    {{ name }} : {{ nums.join(', ') }}
  </div>
</template>


